# center element inside fixed element

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering an element inside another element that's fixed:

bottombanner is inside html body:

```
<div id="bottombanner">
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html">ContactUs</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">AboutUs</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="bugs.html">BugReportBox</a></li>
        <li><a href="suggestions.html">SuggestionBox</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

css is linked properly:

```
    #bottombanner{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    }

    #bottombanner > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    }

    #bottombanner > div > ul {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -webkit-margin-start: auto;
    -webkit-margin-end: auto;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something? It's hard for us to tell how you've implemented this

Comment: What's the HTML that you're applying this to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add height to `#bottombanner` (at least, it was necessary for my fiddle) and add `text-align: center` to `#bottombanner > div`:

```
#bottombanner{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height: 130px;
}

#bottombanner > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#bottombanner > div > ul {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -webkit-margin-start: auto;
    -webkit-margin-end: auto;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/cFgNx/

Comment: To add `height: 100%;` to the `fixed` Element did the trick for me. Thank you Kevin

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the display attribute of the centered element to block and set the width of the element.

```
#bottombanner > div > ul {
 position:relative;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 -webkit-margin-start: auto;
 -webkit-margin-end: auto;
 -webkit-padding-start: 0;
 display:block;
 width:200px;
}
```

Comment: this works when i fix the width, is there a way to do this with width:auto?

Comment: By default, the width of the ul is 100%, so width auto is 100%. If you want the list to contract to the smallest size, you'll have to do something, like float:left, or display: inline-block to shrink it (but I'm not sure which one)